# Width is set before transition occurs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a transition base on hover that will make an image increase its size within 1.5 sec and with 0.5 sec delay, but for some reason the **width** jumps straight to its full size.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h4>Silent Night</h4>
        <img src="assets/axe_silent_night_small.jpg"><a href="#">
        <h5>Add to Cart</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Silent Night</h4>
        <img src="assets/axe_kingmaker_small.jpg"><a href="#">
        <h5>Add to Cart</h5>
    </li>
</ul> 


.store img {
    margin:10px auto ;
    display: block;
    width:auto;
    height:170px;
    transition: width 1.5s, height 1.5s;
    transition-delay:0.5s;
}

.store img:hover {
    height:150%;
    width:150%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i couldn't know about the other thread as i didnt new the auto is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width in the transformation and not width. And set a value on max-width to something bigger than your box will ever get.